# Building a long-distance laser rangefinder

Tags: arduino, usb, laser

I’ve started a new project last week, something that I had had in mind for a long time: building from scratch a long-distance laser rangefinder.

Unfortunately, after going through all of google, the closest thing to my project I came across were a [2010](https://academicworks.cuny.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1034&context=cc_etds_theses) and a ‘99 thesis article.

Do you guys have any indication on where to start? Could I just use the link above and put a more powerful laser in order to make it work for longer distances (2 km)?

Comment: You can go buy an Arduino time of flight sensor for a few dollars, so that's a good place to start. The challenge with long range will be the optical design. Unless you're planning range find high quality retroreflectors, at multiple km range you will need quite a laser and some telescope optics in the receiver.

Comment: Given this is on the order of 2 km and that it must work in broad daylight (guessing) then this is pretty much what airborne LiDAR does. You may need to look up terms like OAM (orbital angular momentum) and the really nifty and important idea of a "photon sieve" in order to separate scattered sunlight from backscattered laser light. Should be a fun project.

Comment: Maybe you should try to build it as-presented (60m) and get it working like that first rather than immediately building it with a high power transmitter and high sensitivity receiver.

Comment: @DKNguyen It was tested at less than 5 m, I believe. (They mention 60 m in the beginning. But don't actually achieve it.) I'm also comfortable concluding it was tested in controlled lab circumstances. A project with significant "unknowns" to resolve (and a very different emitter/sensor approach is needed for km distances in daylight) should have those unknowns pulled to the very front of the project and resolved first. Worrying over simple details (like time-of-flight calcs) is pointless if "km in daylight" is not nailed down beforehand. That's the place to start. Not building this thing IMHO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help guys ! After a bit more research I ended up on a Canadian masters thesis that was very close to what I wanted to develop ! 
https://research.library.mun.ca/14466/1/thesis.pdf

I’ll probably start from there

Comment: @JohnPilly I think you might be underappreciating the amount of expertise that went into that thesis – probably not even by the student who wrote it themselves, but also by the lab they worked in! Personally, as a thesis advisor, I must say that the scope was very wide – and unless the student was *very* capable and extremely motivated, dangerously close to being unfairly wide (unfair to the student, who had to work more than he then gets credit for). You'd be much better off starting with readily made and qualified optics and mechanics. This is really a lot of effort to get right, and it

Comment: looks like the student had to *also* do FPGA development and signal processing themselves. Certainly not an impossible task, but it requires master-thesis-level skills in two or three engineering disciplines (mechanical engineering, optics and electrical engineering, where, depending on who you ask, optics is its own discipline, or handled by MEs or by EEs.)

Comment: So, to avoid raining on your parade, and thinking what you want to do is extremely cool, I'd say what @periblepsis says, but maybe bit nicer: What you've set out to solve is a problem for a class of hard problems. You should hence be sure which problem you actually want to solve, otherwise you *will* be wasting a lot of money, time and motiivation – and I believe the last one to be an especially valuable resource here, as this project will not be without its frustrations:

Comment: You never read about most of the things that *did not* work during a thesis, and the amount of frustration and self-doubt a lot of students designing complex things for the first time go through; source: I was the advisor to quite a few student theses. Set yourself a definite specification that has been proven to work; neither of the theses you cite actually showed that their devices worked for the range you want; and even that impressive thesis by Morgan tactfully puts a "N/A" on range in the final outcome table. This project really calls for reading a book on laser rangefinding:

Comment: *Spending two days in a lab can easily save you up to one hour reading literature*, but in this case, think in months of things that you don't get to work compared to days reading a book to learn what even theoretically can and can't work.

Comment: @MarcusMüller FMCW might be another approach. But here (and with some other methods) there are expensive filters (narrow band thin film optical, polarization of the right kind) and optical mechanicals and lenses. Regardless of the mechanisms chosen, the *known unknowns* must be pulled to the front of the project and proven out, first. That's priority one. Nothing else matters. Chances are they will find other *unknown unknowns* that need to be solved, as well. It's the way of things. Projects like this have a habit of unearthing stuff you had no idea of, before.

Comment: @Marcus and the others : 1st Huge thanks for your interest in the project ! 
Tbh you are totally right, I am not planning on starting 100% from scratch like it is done in the thesis. 
My ideal scenario would be using Arduino + Arduino Laser Modules. There are a lot of projects online that build small range rangefinder (up to 50 meters), but almost nothing at 1km or above…

Comment: Yeah, because problems get much much harder when you go twenty times as wide: the quality of optics necessary for such a long range puts the equipment solidly out of the range of "Arduino accessory", financially. Again. Get a book, and write down definitive specifications you need to achieve, in hard numbers, without using wordings like "or above". Check against literature. You don't realize what the difference between 50 and 1000 m causes.